# tikz cd: ! I can't find file `librarycd.code.tex'

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, installing, tikz-cd

The cd package for tikz seems to be failing, or missing. I am using Kile in Ubuntu 10.4, and I installed all the tikz-related packages my package manager could find.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}


\begin{document}

bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you got the file on your computer?

Comment: @yo' Thanks! No, I can't find the file either...

Comment: @Gale Which version of Ti*k*Z are you using? Would the package `tikz-cd` be feasible for you?

Comment: @Gale does your error persist? Have you been able to update your version of Ti*k*Z?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `tikz-cd` package. It is not directly part of TikZ. Possibly not even part of your Linux package manager. You could get it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) then.

Then, load the `tikz-cd` package:

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
```

But, alternatively, this should work then too:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
```